# Have the header/toolbar remain static at the top of the page during scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On many sites now, say you have a toolbar/table-header that is midway in the page.
Once you start scrolling, you can't see the header or toolbar anymore so you can't perform actions on any rows you may have selected, or you can't see the name's of the headers of the columns.

Many sites do this now, which is great, when you start to scroll the toolbar/header is fixed at the top of the browser.  This doesn't happend right away, only when you scroll down to the point where the header/toolbar would normally not be visible.

How can I do this?  Is there a name for this functionality?

**Gmail has this, if you scroll down when reading an email, the toolbar at the top is fixed at the top so you can label/move/spam the email.**

Comment: though I have not understood the second sentence of the second paragraph... plain css can "fix" a div (or whatever) to the top (or wherever you want); maybe for the behaviour explained in "This doesn't happend right away..." (which I have not understood), javascript would be needed; something like http://www.robertcailliau.eu/Alphabetical/zAlphabetical-en.html ?

Comment: I think I understand what you want: an element that stays with content when you scroll, until it would scroll off the page, at which point it becomes fixed in place. If so, edit your question, the wording is really confusing. (Maybe link to an example site, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery Waypoints - Sticky elements](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/), should be what you're looking for.

Comment: bing! yes this is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
.static{
  position:fixed;
}
```

And then, put a `class="static"` to your header element.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I think Blankman is looking for an element that moves with content and then becomes fixed to the window edge instead of scrolling off the page. So not as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript to solve this problem — don't make it harder on yourself. Using fixed positioning forces the header to "hover" above your content, and when you scroll, remain at the top of your screen, not at the top of the page. You can use this CSS to make your header fixed.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Make sure you assign the class "header" to your div. For design reasons, I'd suggest keeping your header at the very top of the screen and stretching all the way across. You can use this CSS to do so.

```
.header {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Technically, you don't need to specify "top" or "left" positioning, but it ensures you don't have anything to go wrong if you do decide to change something like that later. You can take a look at other types of positioning at [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).